# Is the aggregation and analysis of data gathered through Facebook Graph API legal

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been building an app that uses Facebook's graph API to gather publicly available data such as a page's feed, post interactions (reactions, comments and such). Testing my queries with Graph API Explorer, they allow me to access all of this data.

As I can see a lot of potential to glean actionable insights through the gathering and analysis of for ex. reactions to posts from several pages (I do not own nor administrate these pages) it is something I would love to do and make my models available to the public.

Reading the platform policy at https://developers.facebook.com/policy/
and the somewhat hidden Automated Data Collection Terms at https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

as well as scouring forums, help centers and stack overflow I've been unable to find an answer.

To the point my questions are:

1. Is it legal to gather, store and analyze data (keeping in accordance to the sections 2.9 (delete the data if the user sets it to private) and of course the entire platform policy)?
2. Beyond that is it legal to sell insights gleaned from aggregates of that data (no user privacy will be even remotely violated).
3. Am I correct in assuming the automated data gathering policy applies only to programs such as web crawlers (i.e. they do not apply when using the graph API policy)?

Thank you for helping, I know this is not strictly a development issue but I've found nowhere else to turn. If however you can refer me to a place/contact within Facebook's support where I would have such and inquiry answered, please do so.

Miha

P.S. I'm not sure if they use graph API, but socialbakers is a comparable service to what I would like to provide.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question, but about legal issues/compliance to some platforms terms and policies.

Comment: 3.9 in the Platform Policy say: "Don't sell, license, or purchase any data obtained from us or our services".